# app using significant location manger closes unexpectedly on devices but not on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios6, location

I hope some one can help me. I'm developing a iOS 6 app on xcode 4.5.2, the app use significant-change location service, it detects the localization uses reverse geocoding and upload the country code, adminArea, subAdminArea, locality and sublocality to an online DB using a web service. on the iphone simulator it works fine, but on iOS devices it directly get closed with no reason. if i deactivate the location services to my app it runs ok, but when it have permission to use these it closes within one second.

this is the code:

```
        #import "searchViewController.h"
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
    #import "resultViewController.h"

    @interface searchViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *errorSearchTextView;
    - (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *bloodTypePicker;

    @end

    @implementation searchViewController

    @synthesize bloodType,locationManager,geocoder, webData, xmlParser, soapResults, localizacion, usuarios, correos, coincidencias;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    bloodType = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A+", @"A-", @"B+", @"B-", @"O+", @"O-", @"AB+", @"AB-", nil];
    [self startLocating];//here is where i start the location monitoring
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

//this is the metod that starts the location manager.

```
- (void) startLocating
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])//si los servicios de localizacion estan activados.
    {
        if (nil == locationManager) {
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        }
    } else
    {
        self.errorSearchTextView.text = NSLocalizedString(@"location services are not available, app will not work properly, please activate these and restart the app.", @"localization not available");
    }
}
```

//these are the methods called when a location update is received.

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    [self geocoder:location];
    localizacion = 0;
}

//metodo para el geocoder
-(void) geocoder:(CLLocation *)location
{
    if (!geocoder) geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if ([placemarks count]>0)
        {
            NSString *usuario = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"usuario"];
            CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"here goes the web service url"];
            NSMutableString *soapMessage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:urn=\"urn:localizacionWSDL\">"
             "<soapenv:Header/>"
             "<soapenv:Body>"
                "<urn:actualiza soapenv:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
             "<username xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:usuario];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</username>"
             "<latitude xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude] ];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</latitude>"
             "<longitude xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude]];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</longitude>"
             "<countryCode xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:place.ISOcountryCode];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</countryCode>"
             "<adminArea xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:place.administrativeArea];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</adminArea>"
             "<subAdminArea xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:place.subAdministrativeArea];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</subAdminArea>"
             "<locality xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:place.locality];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</locality>"
             "<subLocality xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">"];
            [soapMessage appendString:place.subLocality];
            [soapMessage appendString:@"</subLocality>"
             "</urn:actualiza>"
             "</soapenv:Body>"
             "</soapenv:Envelope>"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *theResquest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
            [theResquest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [theResquest addValue:@"urn:LoginAction" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
            [theResquest addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [theResquest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [theResquest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            webData = [NSMutableData data];
            localizacion = 0;
            NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theResquest delegate:self];
            if (theConnection) {
                self.errorSearchTextView.text = NSLocalizedString(@"BloodyHelp is updating your data.", @"updating location");
            } else {
                self.errorSearchTextView.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Conection error.\n", @"connection error updating");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I really don't know what to do. cause in the simulator everything works fine.
P.D. I'm new progamming at objetive-c

Edit: to add crash report

```
Incident Identifier: C14368BA-39ED-454F-930C-1D2CB94FB299
CrashReporter Key:   1eeb5e6ac17a73185e6d73aeb7aa4da7e7edab94
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         XXXX [2221]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/901983D5-A1AA-4642-A858-9E211D0AA09E/xxxx.app/xxxx
Identifier:      xxxxxx
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-03-01 11:35:58.829 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3302629e 0x3aebf97a 0x330261c0 0x32ff576e 0x6fba8 0x3b2d711a 0x3b2d64b2 0x3b2db1b8 0x32ff9f36 0x32f6ceb8 0x32f6cd44 0x36b1f2e6 0x34e822fc 0x6d7ea 0x3b2f6b1c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3bd350 0x3b3ac000 + 70480
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b33411e 0x3b305000 + 192798
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b37096e 0x3b305000 + 440686
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a90ed4a 0x3a90b000 + 15690
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a90bff4 0x3a90b000 + 4084
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aebfa74 0x3aeb7000 + 35444
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a90c078 0x3a90b000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a90c110 0x3a90b000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a90d50e 0x3a90b000 + 9486
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aebf9ba 0x3aeb7000 + 35258
10  CoreFoundation                  0x330261c0 0x32f64000 + 795072
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32ff576e 0x32f64000 + 595822
12  appname                     0x0006fba8 0x6c000 + 15272
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b2d711c 0x3b2d5000 + 8476
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b2d64b4 0x3b2d5000 + 5300
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b2db1b8 0x3b2d5000 + 25016
16  CoreFoundation                  0x32ff9f36 0x32f64000 + 614198
17  CoreFoundation                  0x32f6ceb8 0x32f64000 + 36536
18  CoreFoundation                  0x32f6cd44 0x32f64000 + 36164
19  GraphicsServices                0x36b1f2e6 0x36b1a000 + 21222
20  UIKit                           0x34e822fc 0x34e2b000 + 357116
21  appname                     0x0006d7ea 0x6c000 + 6122
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b2f6b1c 0x3b2f5000 + 6940

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3ad648 0x3b3ac000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b2dd974 0x3b2d5000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b2dd654 0x3b2d5000 + 34388

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3aceb4 0x3b3ac000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3ad048 0x3b3ac000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32ffb040 0x32f64000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32ff9d9e 0x32f64000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32f6ceb8 0x32f64000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32f6cd44 0x32f64000 + 36164
6   WebCore                         0x38f52500 0x38f48000 + 42240
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b31630e 0x3b305000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3161d4 0x3b305000 + 70100

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3bdd98 0x3b3ac000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30bcf6 0x3b305000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30ba12 0x3b305000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30b8a0 0x3b305000 + 26784

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3bdd98 0x3b3ac000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30bcf6 0x3b305000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30ba12 0x3b305000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30b8a0 0x3b305000 + 26784

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3aceb4 0x3b3ac000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3ad048 0x3b3ac000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32ffb040 0x32f64000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32ff9d9e 0x32f64000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32f6ceb8 0x32f64000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32f6cd44 0x32f64000 + 36164
6   Foundation                      0x338b93d0 0x3388c000 + 185296
7   Foundation                      0x3393ce80 0x3388c000 + 724608
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b31630e 0x3b305000 + 70414
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3161d4 0x3b305000 + 70100

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3bdd98 0x3b3ac000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30bcf6 0x3b305000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30ba12 0x3b305000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30b8a0 0x3b305000 + 26784

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3bd594 0x3b3ac000 + 71060
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32fff1f2 0x32f64000 + 635378
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b31630e 0x3b305000 + 70414
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b3161d4 0x3b305000 + 70100

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b3bdd98 0x3b3ac000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30bcf6 0x3b305000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30ba12 0x3b305000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b30b8a0 0x3b305000 + 26784

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3ceb1534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ceb1b88      r6: 0x1f0e3e24      r7: 0x2fd93c74
    r8: 0x1f0e3e00    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x38ac0a46     r11: 0x38ac0ce8
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd93c68      lr: 0x3b334123      pc: 0x3b3bd350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
```

Ther is more but it's too long. it's enough?

edit i got the console out:

```
Mar  1 22:08:26 iPad-de-xxx locationd[45] <Notice>: client 'com.appname' starting significant location changes
Mar  1 22:08:26 iPad-de-xxx awdd[3079] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Mar  1 22:08:26 iPad-de-xxx awdd[3079] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Mar  1 22:08:49 iPad-de-xxx awdd[3080] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Mar  1 22:08:49 iPad-de-xxx awdd[3080] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
Mar  1 22:08:52 iPad-de-xxx appname copy[3078] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x330262a3 0x3aebf97f 0x330261c5 0x32ff5773 0xfb85 0x3b2d711f 0x3b2d64b7 0x3b2db1bd 0x32ff9f3b 0x32f6cebd 0x32f6cd49 0x36b1f2eb 0x34e82301 0xd7c7 0x3b2f6b20)
Mar  1 22:08:52 iPad-de-xxxx ReportCrash[3082] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process BloodyHelp copy[3078]
Mar  1 22:08:52 iPad-de-xxxxx com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.appname[0x9e96][3078]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.appname[0x9e96]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Mar  1 22:08:52 iPad-de-xxxxbackboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.appname[0x9e96]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Mar  1 22:08:52 iPad-de-Shimon ReportCrash[3082] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Mar  1 22:08:52 iPad-de-xxx ReportCrash[3082] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/appname copy_2013-03-01-220852_iPad-de-xxxx plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0


*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString appendString:]: nil argument'
```

Comment: Do you get any crash logs?

Comment: Not yet. How can i get these?

Comment: From Xcode menu bar - Window -> Organizer, then click on "Devices" segment, then click disclosure arrow near device in left side bar, then click "Device Logs". Make sure you have the app bundle and dSYM on your machine and indexable by Spotlight so you can symbolicate them.

Comment: Is your app really named BloodyHelp?

Comment: yes it's the real name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve this, the crash logs and the console out was the point to find the exact point of the error and solve it, the problem was not at the location services, the problem was than after make gocoding the sub Adminarea was null and i was trying to append to a string, since it's value was nil it trows an exception and close.

the solution was to create this

```
 NSString *subAdminArea = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%d",place.subAdministrativeArea];
```

so if the value of place.subAdministrativeArea is nil it is an "" Strging.

advice: to solve the problem connect the device to xcode and make the error happen while you see console out, (you can put " console flags" with NSLog to know where  is the error.

Thanks!!